How to convert range into multi-header table?
I've been trying to convert this structure from excel:


What have you tried?

TOCOL function is your friend.

=TOCOL(HSTACK(IFS(A2:A9<>A1:A8,A2:A9),B2:B9),2)
Where IFS checks if the current cell of column A is not equal to the previous and returns the current cell value of column A, else an error value (#N/A). Stacking column B values to this array of values/errors and wrapping them in TOCOL with argument 2 (ignore error values) results in each first new value of column A followed by each value in column B.

Thank you, this is great!
